# why is this function not compiling in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I'm a newbie in Erlang so stay with me.

I've got this function in erlang that I'm trying to compile, through the file `animal.erl`.

```
module(animal).
help_moi(Animal) ->
    Talk = if Animal == cat -> "miaou";
              Animal == beef -> "meuuuh";
              Animal == dog -> "Wouf";
              Animal == tree -> "treee!";
              true -> "ezfezfezf,"
    end, %blablabla%
    {Animal ,"dit", ++ Talk ++ "!" }. %oh là là là%
```

I'm then compiling it with `erl`

```
c(animal).
```

And these the errors , I'm having

```
1> c(animal).
animal.erl:1: syntax error before: '.'
animal.erl:9: syntax error before: '++'
animal.erl:9: no module definition
error
```

I tried to look on google but not much documentations on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module directive starts with a `-` character:

```
-module(animal).
```

And you have an extra comma between `"dit"` and `++ Talk`.

After fixing those two things, I get a warning, not an error:

```
animal.erl:2: Warning: function help_moi/1 is unused
```

You probably want to export the function, so you can call it from outside the module:

```
-export([help_moi/1]).
```

Comment: Hi @legoscia, ty